# Can't install gulp-load-plugins on server

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, npm-install, gulp-load-plugins

I'm trying to install `gulp-load-plugins` on server, but getting error `killed extract:gulp-load-plugins:sill doParallel` extract 516 [image: killed extract:gulp-load-plugins]

`npm -v 4.2.0
node -v 4.7.3
Server : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630L v2 @ 2.40GHz
 OS: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS, Trusty Tahr`

I searched in google a lot, but didn't find any answers. What is the reason of this error? Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in small swap on Ubuntu. Here is an article explain how to add more swap 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04